# Divide and conquer algorithm to sort a list where each element is root(n) away from its sorted position

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

I'm stuck on a question and I just need a hint/point in the general direction (not asking for the answer)

The question asks for the details of a divide and conquer algorithm that given a sequence that is almost sorted, produces the correct order in time O(n).

What they mean by almost sorted is that given the list

> x_1, x_2, .... x_n

if the sorted list is represented by

> y_1, y_2, ... y_n

and for every i, j <= n this property is respected:

> x_i == y_j && |i-j| <= root(n)

The only thing that came to my mind was to divide the lists into root(n) groups at each level (which would cause them to be at most length root(n) for the first split), but I'm not too sure where to go from there, because you'd have to join up root(n) elements at a time as you recurse back up.

I've also figured out that the recursion complexity equation would be:

> T(n) = root(n) * T(n/root(n)) + d * root(n)

which by the `master's theorem` can be proved to be O(n) time.

So it kind of seems like I'm on the right track with the splitting, I'm just not sure if it should be split up in a special way or compared a certain way or what.

**EDIT**: So supposedly this was the correct answer.

> Our algorithm is as follows: If n > 1, then we recursively sort each of the two (approximate) halves of the sequence; now all the elements are in the correct position, except possibly those within √n positions of the middle (do you see why this is true?); so we now do a merge of the elements in those positions. If we let T(n) be the time used to sort nelements, then for n > 1 we have
>
> > T(n)≤2T(⌈n=2⌉) +c * √n
>
> Since √(n) = n<sup>.5</sup> and .5 < 1 = log<sub>2</sub>2, the Master Theorem for Divide and Conquer Recurrences tells us thatT(n)∈O(n).

I'm not sure if I agree since the time to sort both halves would be O(<sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub> * log(<sup>n</sup>⁄<sub>2</sub>)) which works out to be O(n*logn) and the final merge would be O(√n * √n) which is O(n) giving us a total of O(n*logn + n) -> O(n*logn)

Comment: Something's not right here – every comparison sort requires Ω(n log n)  comparisons to sort √n lists of √n elements each.

Comment: The condition x_i == x_j looks fishy...

Comment: Corrected version: a list x(1), ..., x(n) is *almost sorted* iff there exists a permutation pi such that x(pi(1)) <= ... <= x(pi(n)) and, for all i, |i - pi(i)| <= sqrt(n).

Comment: @WolframH You're right, it should read x_i == y_j, I've corrected it now

Comment: I may have overcomplicated the question and possibly implied tighter restrictions on the question. But couldn't you do this with mergesort. We know that at worse case, an element only needs to be compared to 2*root(n) other elements. Then we get a modified mergesort recurrence of T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + 2*root(n), which by masters theorem gives O(n). Or did I miss something else?

Comment: @user8575 Please describe your modified mergesort in more detail (pseudocode would be nice, working code even nicer).

Comment: The proposed solution makes exactly the error that I suspected in my answer: it assumes that for each of the halves the condition "almost sorted" still holds, which is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an algorithm could be used to sort r lists of  r items in O(r*r) time, just by concatening the lists (and decorating the elements, if necessary). However,  it is known that you can't do better than O(r*r*ln(r)), or O(n * ln(n)) for n = r * r.

I guess that either the original question is a littledifferent, or that the person giiving the original question  to you made a mistake when calculating the complexity. Like, for example, assuming that when the list is divided in two halves, both parts are still *almost sorted*. (There are ways to split up the list in this way, like taking every second element, but not every partition of the list will have this property.)

Comment: This was the case. He was assuming that the sorted property held. He ended up retracting the question from the assignment

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible for a comparison based sort to do it in `O(n)`.

Consider the simplified problem where the sorted array is divided into √n buckets, and the elements inside each bucket are shuffled. The condition that each element must be no more than √n positions from its final spot is satisfied.

To solve this you must sort each bucket. Using any `O(n*logn)` sort, you would have √n * (√n*log√n). This is (1/2)*n*logn, which is still `O(n*logn)`.

Since this simplified problem can only be solved in `O(n*logn)`, I conclude that it is impossible to solve the original problem in `O(n)` using a comparison based sort.

If you know, for example, that all the elements are integers within a certain range you are no longer limited to a comparison based sort and may be able to solve the problem in `O(n)` using a non-comparison based sort, such as [pigeon sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort).

Answer (score 0):

First clue: T(n) = root(n) * T(n/root(n)) + d * root(n) is incorrect. Since it is a recursive function it is not true for T(root(n)).

Comment: it would have to be then:
Let k be the number of elements in the original list, then 
T(n) = root(k) * T(n/root(k)) + d * root(n) which would give O(n) but also implies that there will only ever be two recursive calls since the first recursive call would be to T(n/root(k)) = T(root(k)) (since n = k at first), then the second call would be T(root(k)/root(k)) which is T(1). But now I just feel like I'm forcing things to work.